# Windows Update issue 0x800f0900

Tags: windows, windows-update, wsus, window-server-2019

Server info:

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard

OS Version:                10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763

Original Install Date:     1/17/2020, 12:25:18 PM

Having issues installing cumulative updates. It seems to have installed defender and .NET updates fine. But can't get the current (Win 10 (1809) and Server 2019 - Cumulative Update (64-bit) January 10 2023) or previous December update to installed.

If I try it manually it fails with MSI failed with error code -2146498304.

When I try it from WSUS or Microsoft it fails with 2023-01 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2019 for x64-based Systems (KB5022286) - Error 0x800f0900

I have tried to reset windows updates according to the below KB.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/additional-resources-for-windows-update

Ran the SFC /Scannow and the DISM restore health commands The restore health command fails with Error: 0x800f0954

In Googling all these error codes I'm basically chasing my tail.
Everything keeps circling around to the same thing over and over and nothing seems to work, and everything fails

The below is from the windows update log

```
2023/01/13 11:00:13.1374595 7128  8128  Handler         CBS called Error with 0x800f0900, 
2023/01/13 11:00:13.1402237 7128  8128  Handler         CBS called Terminate
2023/01/13 11:00:53.9164837 7128  7556  Handler         Completed install of CBS update with type=0, requiresReboot=0, installerError=1, hr=0x800f0900
2023/01/13 11:00:54.0648649 7128  7556  Handler         * END *   CBS Install
2023/01/13 11:00:54.6929704 3664  5204  Agent           *FAILED* [8024200B] Method failed [CAgentUpdateManager::InstallUpdate:11739]
2023/01/13 11:00:54.8788666 3664  5204  Handler         Loaded state: cCompleteIterations: 1, pt: SelfContainedNoExpressPayload, nNextRequestID: 1.
2023/01/13 11:00:54.9012256 3664  5204  Agent           LogHistory called. idUpdate={447FF6C5-74A0-4DFD-A497-9039E898E010}.200, resultMapped=800F0900, resultUnMapped=800F0900
2023/01/13 11:00:54.9131342 3664  5204  Agent           Install updates CallerId = UpdateOrchestrator
2023/01/13 11:00:54.9132320 2116  4776  ComApi           Install ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
2023/01/13 11:00:54.9140489 2116  4776  ComApi          Install call complete (succeeded = 0, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 1, cancelled = 0, unaccounted = 0
2023/01/13 11:00:54.9143000 2116  4776  ComApi          Reboot required = False
2023/01/13 11:00:54.9143085 2116  4776  ComApi          Exit code = 0x00000000; Call error code = 0x80240022
2023/01/13 11:00:54.9143100 2116  4776  ComApi          * END *   Install ClientId = UpdateOrchestrator
2023/01/13 11:00:54.9146923 3664  1652  Agent           WU client calls back to install call {36B49B40-ED6B-4C7D-A74A-D2CC913B7D67} with code Call complete and error 0 
2023/01/13 11:00:54.9149632 2116  6932  ComApi          Install call complete (succeeded = 0, succeeded with errors = 0, failed = 1, cancelled = 0, unaccounted = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears i may have solved my issue.

1. I deleted all files in C:\Windows\Servicing\Packages\ that i had
   permissions to delete. Mostly all the .MUM files. If i had to do it again i would only delete the effected one. You can find this in the CBS log (C:\Windows\Logs\CBS)
2. Ran the Windows Update fix script to clean
   house.
3. Rebooted
4. Checked for windows update failed
5. Checked again and was able to install the 2023-01 Cumulative Update for Windows
   Server 2019 for x64-based Systems (KB5022286)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been confounding us with some (but not all) 2019 Datacenter servers since November. One is a DC, we've tried SFC and clearing the update cache like you describe with no luck. Last week we were spinning up four new 2019 VMs (Hyper-V) installing them identically "click for click" and when we got to the Windows Update stage two of them installed all the patches fine and two of them errored out like you describe.

Comment: Interesting,  I just tried this see if you get the same error as well.
Try uninstalled one of the older cumulative updates and see if it lets you. mine just errors out with unexpected error.

Comment: Also what does your CBS.log Say?

Comment: I was able to get the latest Update to install.  https://serverfault.com/a/1120465/952571

if you have any questions let me know.